# How to group by domain and delete more than two result in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, grouping

I have a question, 
I would like to group my table and show only MAX two values (eg alphabetically hard) for each domain.
**Table name = table1

MySQL database**

For example:
[image]

**Score:**
**aa@aa.com**
**bb@aa.com**
**aa@example.com

cc@example.com

a@domain.com**

As you can see, the query should group by domain and show only **MAX TWO** records for each domain

Can you help me?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: On my serwer I see : 5.1.73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [MySQL 8.0.2 and above](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/), this problem can be solved using [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) in a less verbose manner.

For [your MySQL version 5.1.73](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967501/how-to-group-by-domain-and-delete-more-than-two-result-in-mysql-database/52967735#comment92841403_52967501), we can emulate this using [Session Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

```
SELECT 
  dt2.Email, 
  dt2.Domain 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    @row_num := IF(@dmn <> dt1.Domain, 1, @row_num + 1) AS row_no, 
    @dmn := dt1.Domain AS Domain, 
    dt1.Email 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      Email, 
      Domain 
    FROM Table1 
    ORDER BY Domain 
  ) AS dt1 
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num := 0, 
                     @dmn := '') AS user_init_vars 
) AS dt2 
WHERE dt2.row_no <= 2 
ORDER BY dt2.Domain
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cVgmPPu9YFJPy8J2CQRiUi/0)

You can follow this tutorial to get a basic idea of how this approach works: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: after a few years I came back to this script and would like to modify it. As I can see after applying it in the database, the script returns more than two records for the Domain.
I would like only two email addresses to be returned for each domain.